# submit function does not trigger onsubmit return function?

Tags: javascript, forms, onsubmit

I think I have a misunderstanding of the onsubmit attribute. I thought that every submission, like a `<input type="submit" ...>`, `<button></button>` or any javascript `form.submit()` trigger the `onsubmit="return function();"` after the submit. In other words, I will never see the "last triggered" log.

Example:

```js
function triggerFirst() {
  console.log("first triggered");
  myForm.submit();  
}

function triggerLast() {
  console.log("last triggered");
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return triggerLast();">
  <input type="button" onclick="triggerFirst();" value="trigger">
</form>
```

This example will never trigger the onsubmit, why? I thought onsubmit means if someone submits? Is that false?

Comment: Probably because `submit() is not defined` is an error

Comment: My mistake. I have added an id to access the form through it explicitly. But no other behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It works.

**UPDATED:**
Place the 2nd function inside first.

```js
function triggerFirst() {
  alert('wow'); 
triggerLast() 
}

function triggerLast() {
alert('wowpsubmit');
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" onsubmit='return triggerLast();'>
  <input type="button" onclick="triggerFirst();" value="trigger" >
</form>
```

Comment: add a myForm.submit(); into your triggerFirst() function and add an alter('wow') to your triggerLast(). Then you dont see the second 'wow', so it doesn't work. My example is not the best, I mean you do something in triggerFirst and only on some cases you want to triggerLast() as a second validation. Your example will never trigger triggerLast() because input does not submit automatically or?

Comment: that will work for this example, but its a workaround. I thought the form.submit() will explicity call the onsubmit="return function();". But it seems that only `<input type="submit" ...>` or `<button onclick="first();"></button>`will call it. But then you dont have the connection between the two functions.

Comment: sorry, I still don't get what you mean

Comment: no problem, probably I explained it vague. see @Rupert 's answer at the bottom. He is exactly doing what I mean, but if I run it, then the submit() function will submit the form, without checking the onsubmit="return function()".

Answer (score 0):

An HTML form does not require javascript to work. Refer the code below:

```
<form action="action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The `<form action="action_page.php">` declaration is run once the form is submitted.

The `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` is a built in type that triggers the form action to run.

See more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In your triggerFirst function the inner function call to submit does nothing. That submit function is not defined. I think here you want to make the function submit so below I passed a reference to the form into the triggerFirst function. This should clarify things for you. Open the console to view the output.

```js
function triggerFirst(form) {
  console.log('triggerFirst')
  console.log(form);
  form.submit();
}

function triggerLast() {
  console.log('triggerLast')
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return triggerLast();">
  <input type="button" onclick="triggerFirst(this.form);" value="trigger">
</form>
```

Comment: thats exactly what I try to do, but I will never see the triggerLast log :-/. If i debug it, the form will submit after form.submit() and never steps into the triggerLast();